# Filter contactlist with viber/line/hike accounts

Tags: android, line, android-contentprovider, contacts, viber

I am building an android app. I need to filter my contacts based on users of whatsapp, line, hike, viber. I used

```
String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile'";
```

to identify to get whatsapp users. Is it possible to identify users of other line,hike and viber ?

Answer (score -1):

You can query the `MIMETYPE` table to get all the rows then looking at the results you can find the `MIMETYPE` string used by hike, viber etc

Alternatively you can add the accounts on a rooted device and pull the `contacts2.db` to figure out the `MIMETYPE` for those accounts.

Also make a note of the string used for `ACCOUNT_TYPE` column. The alternate solution for this is to query based on the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` - this would return the contacts which are part of that account. Typically such applications copy contact to there own account type and then add their specific `MIMETYPE`.